# Как добавить поля в существующий метабокс на wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с формой комментирования. Добавляю 2 мета поля *job* и *city*

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'extend_comment_custom_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'extend_comment_custom_fields' );
function extend_comment_custom_fields() {

    echo '<p class="comment-form-job">'.
              '<label for="job">' . esc_attr__( 'Ваша профессия','credit7') . '</label>'.
              '<input id="job" name="job" type="text" size="30"/></p>';

    echo '<p class="comment-form-city">'.
              '<label for="city">' . esc_attr__( 'Город проживания','credit7') . '</label>'.
              '<input id="city" name="city" type="text" size="30"/></p>';
}

add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_extend_comment_meta_data' );
function save_extend_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ){

    if( !empty( $_POST['job'] ) ){
        $job = sanitize_text_field($_POST['job']);
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'job', $job );
    }

    if( !empty( $_POST['city'] ) ){
        $city = sanitize_text_field($_POST['city']);
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'city', $city );
    }

}
```

Теперь мне нужно их вывести в админке. Если добавить так:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_comment', 'extend_comment_add_meta_box' );
function extend_comment_add_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box( 'title', __( 'Comment Metadata - Extend Comment' ), 'extend_comment_meta_box', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

// Отображаем наши поля
function extend_comment_meta_box( $comment ){
    $job  = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'job', true );
    $city  = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'city', true );

    wp_nonce_field( 'extend_comment_update', 'extend_comment_update', false );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="job"><?php esc_attr__( 'Ваша профессия','credit7'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="job" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $job ); ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="city"><?php esc_attr__( 'Город проживания','credit7'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $city ); ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

То они попадают в отдельный метабокс.
А как добавить их в существующий метабокс (на скрине), чтобы они следовали один за одним и не разделялись по блокам?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо добавлять метабоксы. Надо изменить существующий. В общем как-то так надо https://wp-kama.ru/id_8342/kak-dobavit-proizvolnye-polya-v-formu-kommentariev-wordpress.html

Comment: @SeVlad да, как раз в статье и написано про добавление нового метаполя `add_meta_box( 'title', __( 'Comment Metadata - Extend Comment' ), 'extend_comment_meta_box', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' )`
Меня же интересует, как отредактировать существующее добавив в него поля